Keep selected option when validation errors occur
I have a form that deletes a selected option (Office field on the gif) when there is a validation error.  The other fields that had data entered remains in the field.  I would like the Office field to keep the selected data if there is a validation error in a different field.  How do I change the form to keep the selected option?

I've tried the code below, but it doesn't work.
 <select name="officename" id="ofiicename" class="form-control @error('officename') is-invalid @enderror">
                    <option value="">--Select the office--</option>
                    @foreach($clients as $val)
                    <option value="{{ $val->firstname }}" {{ old('officename') == $val->firstname ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $val->firstname }}</option>

Saving selected option after validation in Laravel I can't use this code because all options for the dropdown aren't listed in the form.  Some options can be added later in a backend module.

Do you have any javascript that modifies the dropdown? As a test, you can add {{ old('officename')}} in your office label just to see what is populated.

You may use javascript to select the option. You can pass the old value from laravel to a javascript value and then select the option based off that.
<script>
var oldValue = {{ old('officename') }};
var mySelect = document.getElementById('ofiicename');

for(var i, j = 0; i = mySelect.options[j]; j++) {
    if(i.value == oldValue) {
        mySelect.selectedIndex = j;
        break;
    }
}
</script>

